# Concatenate all filenames inside a folder in a variable within a Batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm trying to create a file list to pass to a program as an argument but i'm having problems with it.

My desired output should be: `file1.jpg, file2.bmp, file3.docx`

The bat i'm trying to use is this:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D %~dp0
set _filelist=
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b %CD%') do (
  set "_filelist=%_filelist%,%%f"
)
echo %_filelist%
pause
```

But it only output the last file in the list: `,lastfile.xyz`

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. check the comment on your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you simply forgot to use the *exclamation mark* ("`!`") with the variable you set within the loop, and to resolve to simply use `!_filelist!` rather than `%_filelist%`.

The below script will set the initial `set _filelist=,` variable with a single comma value so the first iteration will be `,,` and then the first iterated value rather than the null plus one comma you get two back to back commas giving a unique pattern to work with for parsing.

You can use [Variable Replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) functionality to parse out the double commas (`,,`), and replace those with a blank value. The final iterated and set variable value will then be parsed from outside the loop with `set _filelist=%_filelist:,,=%` removing the double comma prefixed value.

### Script

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D %~dp0
set _filelist=,
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b %CD%') do (
  set "_filelist=!_filelist!,%%f"
)
set _filelist=%_filelist:,,=%
echo %_filelist%
pause
```

> *Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be
>   expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is
>   turned on with the SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion command.* <sup>[[1]](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> *When delayed expansion is in effect, variables can be immediately read
>   using !variable_name! you can also still read and use %variable_name%
>   that will show the initial value (expanded at the beginning of the
>   line).* <sup>[[1]](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)</sup>

---

### Further Resources

- [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) <sup>[1]</sup>

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i was in a hurry here.
Well, the script works like a charm, but before the file list i always get an extra `,` at the beginning of the line, like:

`,file1.xxx,file2,xxx`.

Is possible to eliminate this very first comma?

Comment: Give me a few and I'll see what I can come up with. Have a few meetings so it may be a few hours.

Comment: Using this line only the last filename is returned.

Comment: The question is worse... In the first iteration obviously the `filelist` variable still havent any value, anyway the comma is added plus the very first filename in the list. So I need to figure out how to "filter" out the comma in that very first iteration.

Comment: @Vico See the amended **Bonus Example** section at the bottom explaining what I used, etc. but from what I tested, it works as expected.